# Does JavaMailSender make DNS call before each send?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dns, jakarta-mail, round-robin

I have a class:

```
@Service
public class MyEmailService {

    public SendEmailResponse sendEmail(...) {
        try {
            ...
            javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
         ...
```

In configuration, the mail server is set as a DNS name. But this DNS could be resolved by different IP addresses. DNS round robin is implemented this way. For me it is a way of load balancing between servers.

To make it working I have to make sure that javaMailSender will make DNS query before each request. I haven't found anything about it in documentation. Could you please help?

Comment: JakartaMail delegates this to Java itself, which does perform some form of DNS caching, see the duplicate for details how to configure its TTL.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Thank you